# Limit a date in input type date

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I would like to limit the date so that the user does not have to select a date of less than one year, but I wish that it is done automatically compared to the date of the system. If anyone has ideas I'm grateful.

Comment: why not using `min` and `max` HTML attributes to achieve that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date using min max can be achieved for safari browser it need to be validated either using polyfill or on click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current date and subtract an year from the current year and set `min` attribute

```js
var dtToday = new Date();

    var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = dtToday.getDate();
    var year = dtToday.getFullYear();

    if(month < 10)
        month = '0' + month.toString();
    if(day < 10)
        day = '0' + day.toString();

    var minDate = (year-1) + '-' + month + '-' + day;    
    document.getElementById('dt').setAttribute('min', minDate);
```

```html
<input type="date"  id="dt">
```

Comment: your code seems to be what I'm looking for, could you explain to me please or just put some comment

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `min` and `max` property for the input element:

```js
let input = document.querySelector("#test");

let nextYear = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1));
let today = new Date();

input.max = formatDate(nextYear)

input.min = formatDate(today)

function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="test"/>
```